# Axios not calling localhost API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, axios, n-tier-architecture

I have a 3 tier application. React as the frontend, flask as the backend, and MySQL as the database. I completed the application and works well locally. I then pushed this code into the AWS Instance for high availability but got this error.

```
xhr.js:160 POST http://localhost:5000/authenticate net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is my codebase for the backend

```
@app.route('/authenticate', methods=['POST'])
def singing():

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

frontend:

```
handleSubmitClose(){
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/authenticate', {
        "username": this.state.username,
        "password": this.state.password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response of HandleSubmitClose - Main Page")
        console.log(response);
```

both of them are on the same ec2 instance and inside the same docker. I am not able to understand that even tho both of them are on the same instance, why is Axios not able to get the flask hostname or am I missing something here.

Trick:
If I change the Axios from localhost to my ec2 public IP, it works. But it's not a good solution cause I am putting this instance into the auto-scaling group where I would not know the public IP or it would be dynamic. So, this solution wouldn't be feasible

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to Flask and not Axios. Solving the issue would be by changing `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` to `app.run(host='localhost')`. Otherwise when calling the HTTP Request, change the URL from localhost to your ec2 public IP.

Comment: @im2mado, I changed from 0.0.0.0 to localhost but to no avail. I am still not convinced why Axios is not calling the flask hostname internally. Is there any other way?